# Are my git files to most recent version?

Tags: git

I would like to run a command to find out "is this the most current version of these files?"

The goal here it so find out: "are the files I have here ahead or behind what's in the repo?" ... and ... if there is a difference, which ones are different (so I can later run git diff)

In that same vein, how do I find the order of commits? (In subversion, it was an integer, and it was obvious that 41 was behind 42. In git ... they are all hashes.

Comment: If you don't have any git GUI: run `git diff`, newest/newer commits will be placed on top of your list.

Comment: Git does this automatically. Set up a local branch `master` which tracks `master` on the remote, `git fetch` and then `git status`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is not well formed—because, in part at least, as you noted, hashes are not conducive to ordering.

As it turns out, though, there isn't an order in the first place.  Or, more precisely, there is a [*partial order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition) but not necessarily any single *total order*.  This is true even in Mercurial, which (like Subversion) has a linearly increasing revision count (so that there is a revision 41 followed by a revision 42, if there are at least 43 revisions), because these Mercurial revision numbers are *local:* they are specific to one particular clone of a repository.  Another clone of the same repository can have the same commits in it, but in another order.

(Mercurial's sequential revision numbers are assigned when revisions are first stored in the repository, but two clones that drift out of sync with each other, then are resynchronized, will contain the same *commits* in a different *order*.  For instance, in your own repository X, commit 41 clearly comes before 42.  But this is because you wrote #41 ... and when your #41 gets into your co-worker's repository Y, your #41 becomes *their* #42, because they wrote what's now your #42 while you were writing your #41.  They committed theirs to their repository Y, where it became *their* #41.  Then you each gave the other one commit and got one commit *from* the other, and that's how it is that you both have a #41 and a #42, but in opposite orders.)

This property is fundamental to any distributed version control system: Subversion can only provide this unique linearization because it is *not* distributed; instead, a central server assigns revision numbers.  (In theory, one could build a distributed system that uses *reservations* from a centralized server, where there might be holes in the numbering, but the numbering would otherwise be sequential.  I have never seen anyone do that though.  It presents interesting synchronization issues.  In particular, you cannot distribute a commit whose reserved number has been superseded; instead, you must obtain a new, higher number.)

Going back to the problem at hand, though, let's define enough items to see how Git deals—or, sometimes, doesn't deal—with this.

#### What's in a repository

First, Git has the *repository*, which stores a set of *commits*, and three other object types.  The other three are *annotated tags*, *trees*, and *blobs* (files, essentially).  Annotated tags are not necessary to the storage model so we can ignore them, while trees map between object hashes and file / path names, and blobs simply store uninterpreted file data.

The *commit* is the most interesting object type here.  It stores:

- a tree ID, so as to store a snapshot of files;
- any number of *parent commit* IDs, but usually just 1: this determines the ordering of commits;
- an *author* (user name, email address, and timestamp);
- a *committer* (same as author except instead of "who wrote the code" it's "who put that code into the repository": this is meant to handle emailed patches, for instance); and
- an arbitrary commit message.

Besides these commits, a repository also stores a number of *references*, the most user-oriented of these being *branch names* (like `master`) and *tag names* (like `v1.2`).  A *reference* is merely a name / object-ID pair, and a branch reference is constrained to contain only the ID of a commit object.  If the name `master` contains the ID `1234567` (shortened), we say that `master` *points to* commit `1234567`.  Tag names often point to tag objects, instead of pointing directly to commits; but if so, the tag object then points to the commit.<sup>1</sup>

Besides the commits and other objects, a repository also contains an *index*.  The index has several roles but the important one here, for our purposes, is that it is where you have Git build up the *next* commit you will make.  The index starts out populated with the contents of the *current* commit.  You then `git add` files to update them, or to add new ones to the index.  When you `git commit` the result, Git takes the current index contents and makes a commit from them—though it's much more precise to say that it turns the index into some tree objects, then makes a commit whose `tree` is the top level tree it just made.

Most repositories also include a *work tree* (spelled with or without a hyphen, and sometimes called "working tree").  The work tree is simply a place where your files have the form that the rest of the computer can deal with: you can edit them, compile them (if they're source code), and so on, and programs like editors and compilers and web servers can read them.  The files actually stored inside the repository are in a Git-only format, so the work tree provides an area where you can actually *use* them, and work on them.

---

<sup>1</sup>Tag objects are in fact allowed to point to any other object, including another tag, or a tree or blob.  This ability mostly goes unused though.

---

#### Commits contain snapshots

Note that in the description above, I mention that `git commit` turns the current index into some tree(s) and makes a commit from the top level tree.  This saves the files in whatever form they were last `git add`ed.  This means that *every commit* has *every file* as of that commit, whole and intact.  This takes less space than you might expect at first because most commits retain most files unchanged from the previous commit—so they just end up re-using the underlying Git blob object.  Also, every Git object is stored with [zlib compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) (and beyond that, eventually Git objects are "packed", but that's beyond the scope of this answer).  So despite every commit having a complete copy of every file, Git repositories tend not to bloat up much at all.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>The glaring exception to this rule occurs if you commit many slight variations of large compressed files, such as bzipped or gzipped tar files.  In this case you defeat Git's packed file storage format and despite packing, the repositories rapidly grow and become unworkable.  If you allow Git to store the unpacked, never-compressed archive, Git's storage system works well and the repository remains manageable.

---

#### Commits form a graph; the graph determines the order

When a commit `C` contains another commit's ID as `C`'s parent, we say that `C` *points to* its parent, just as we say that `master` points to some commit.  So if there are three commits in the repository, with `A` being the first one, `B` being the second, and `C` being the last, we can draw a *graph*:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- master
```

Here `master` points to `C`; `C` points back to `B`; and `B` points back to `A`.  `A` does not point back anywhere earlier—it can't; it was the first commit.  It has *no* parents, and is called a *root commit*.

Git *finds* these commits using the name `master`.  The branch name—or indeed, any Git reference at all—acts as a key to get Git started, providing the big ugly hash ID.  Once Git can find commit `C`, it uses `C` to find `B` and `B` to find `A`.

We call `B` and `C` *descendants* of `A`, and `A` and `B` are *ancestors* of `C`.  The arrows connecting "child" back to "parent" are one-way links, so it's relatively hard to find the children of a commit, given that commit; but it's trivial to find the parents.

Branches, if there are any, occur because two descendants eventually share a parent.  For instance—I'll stop drawing the internal arrows—consider this graph:

```
A--B--C     <-- mainline
    \
     D--E   <-- feature
```

Here there are two names to get Git started.  One gets Git started at commit `C`, and the other at commit `E`.  Following the internal backwards arrows, we go from `E` to `D` to `B`, and from `C` to `B`.  (And, we go from `B` to `A` as usual, but now that it's all one common line, it's not as interesting anymore.)

We say that commits `A--B--C` are "on branch mainline", and commits `A--B--D--E` are "on branch feature".  That is, commits `A` and `B` are on *both* branches.  **This idea is peculiar to Git.**  Mercurial, for instance, does *not* do this (with named branches anyway; you can have anonymous Mercurial heads within a single branch, and then the same issue crops up, with the same effect).  It's also worth noting that we can draw this same graph a bit differently to emphasize the sharing:

```
     C      <-- mainline
    /
A--B
    \
     D--E   <-- feature
```

In any case, though, the key concepts are that **commits can be on *many* branches at the same time, and that the *order* of commits is determined through these parent/child, ancestor/descendant relationships.**

#### What this means for your original question

You wanted to know how you can tell if a file is "ahead of" or "behind" some particular commit, and the answer is, you can't.  Suppose, for instance, that you have file `README.txt` and can examine its contents; and suppose your repository has the five commits `A` through `E` from the graph above.

Suppose further that `README.txt` matches the `README.txt` in commits `B`, `D`, and `E`, but not the one in `A`, and not the one in `C`.  Is `README.txt` *ahead of* something?  Is it *behind* something?  Well, it *matches* `B`, `D`, and `E`; but that's all we can say.

If we take a larger collection of files—such as an entire work-tree—we can compare it to any commit at all.  But again, we'll either get "it matches" or "it doesn't match".  If it doesn't match, `git diff` will give you a set of *instructions*: "here is how to change the commit to make it look like the work-tree" (or vice versa, your choice).  But again, you can't tell if this is *ahead*, or *behind*, or just kind of mixed up (if you've deliberately extracted each individual file from a commit chosen at random, for instance—who knows why, perhaps a fit of midnight madness :-) ).

#### What you *can* tell about commits

What you *can* do, quite easily, is determine whether one commit is an *ancestor* of another commit.  For instance, given just two commit hashes, like `badf00d` and `c0ffee1`, we can ask: is one of them "before" the other?  If `badf00d` happens to be the ID of commit `B` and `c0ffee1` is the ID of commit `E`, then yes, `badf00d < c0ffee1`.

But what if `badf00d` is the ID, not of `B`, but rather of `C`?  Does `C` come "before" `E`?  Does `E` come before `C`?  The answer might be [mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)), in the Hofstader and Persig sense, for instance.

(To test this, use `git merge-base --is-ancestor`:

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor badf00d c0ffee1
```

which returns a true, i.e., 0, exit status if the first commit is an ancestor of the second.  Note that if the answer is "no", you must still repeat the test reversed, lest neither be an ancestor of the other.)

Comment: Tremendous answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare(`diff`) your files with `remote/<branch>` to find if there is any change.

```
$ git fetch
$ git diff HEAD..origin/master       # diff with origin/master (remote master)
```